# VB6 Server.CreateObject("WebClassRuntime.WebClassManager") fails on Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp-classic, vb6, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to get a VB6 Webclasses application running a Windows Server 2008 box.  I was successful on one, and went to repeat my steps be sure before sending it off to QA and it doesn't work on the second server.

I have the application pool set to .NET 2.0 and Enable 32bit = true.  ASP and IIS6 Metabase Compatibility are installed on the server.  Under my Application > ASP, I set Enable Parent Paths to True.  I have copied over and registered the dlls specific to the app, as well as MSWCRUN.dll, des-56.dll, dzactx.dll, MSINET.ocx, msscript.ocx, MSVBVM50.dll, MSVBVM60.dll, and scrrun.dll.

When I try to hit the app, I get a 500 Server Error.  In the IIS logs, I can see the following: "ASP_0177_:_800a01f3|Server.CreateObject_Failed 443".  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I found it using Process Monitor.  There were 2 versions of the dll for my code with different names and I had registered the wrong one.