# Error Showing .asp file?

Tags: asp.net

I have recently changed the server for one my domain. This domain was build in asp file but I have found some links are not working properly and redirecting to BIZyCart.asp and showing some error which is below mentioned:

```
<%
Server.ScriptTimeout=30
Response.Buffer=True
Response.Expires=0

If (VarType(Application("~WC~WebClassManager")) = 0) Then
Application.Lock
If (VarType(Application("~WC~WebClassManager")) = 0) Then
    Set Application("~WC~WebClassManager") = Server.CreateObject("WebClassRuntime.WebClassManager")
End If
Application.UnLock
End If

Application("~WC~WebClassManager").ProcessNoStateWebClass "BIZyCart_VB.BIZyCart", _
    Server, _
    Application, _
    Session, _
    Request, _
    Response
%>
```

So Please help me to solve this and let me know where is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are [using a COM object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524620(v=vs.90).aspx) in your classic ASP. Below line creates this COM object.

```
Server.CreateObject("WebClassRuntime.WebClassManager")
```

Since you changed your domain this COM object does not exist in your new domain. You need to find dll file for your this COM object and [register it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683954(v=vs.85).aspx) in your new domain. 
Well. Finally I found vbscript register [reference](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/ImageMagickObject.php).

To register the DLL as a COM+ server, type

```
regsvr32 /c /s YOURDLLNAME.dll
```

To unregister the DLL, type

```
regsvr32 /u /s YOURDLLNAME.dll
```

You need to find necessary dll file(s) otherwise your page will not work. See [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386263/vb6-server-createobjectwebclassruntime-webclassmanager-fails-on-windows-serv), it lists some dll names for your COM object.

Comment: thanks for reply but i am new in asp and i do not know to ro register it. i have some files in server but not find any DLL. so please help me where and how can i register the DLL